# CloudFlare не допускает запросы к API поддомену после включения Under Attack Mode

Tags: node.js, cors, cloudflare

Сайт на домене:  site.ru
API сервер по адресу: api.site.ru

При обычной работе CloudFlare, проблем не наблюдается

При включенной защите Under Attack Mode возникает ошибка CORS при выполнении запроса используя метод POST с сайта на API

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Under attack mode prevent api request](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/under-attack-mode-prevent-api-request/152263/4)

Comment: @Simon я все ровно не понимаю как быть в данной ситуации